# grails hasMany of jodatime Instants

Tags: grails, groovy, jodatime

How can I work around http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPJODATIME-28 which prevents a domain class from having a hasMany of any extended type?
I'm thinking of switching the whole app to persisting a custom UserType derived from BigDecimal for posix epoch dates. Seem's like a hammer for a walnut though. IS there another approach I could take?

```
import org.joda.time.Instant    
class Foo {    
    Instant birthday 

    Set favoriteDays = []

    static hasMany = [
        favoriteDays : Instant
    ]

    static constraints = {
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I'm not missing something in your question but I've done things like this:

Create a class called `MyInstant` and use it in the `hasMany`

```
import org.joda.time.Instant   
class MyInstant {
    Instant myInstant
    //anything else you might need
}

class Foo {
    MyInstant birthday

    Set favoriteDays = []
    static hasMany = [favoriteDays: MyInstant]
}
```

I've tested this in the `FooController`:

```
import org.joda.time.Instant
class FooController {
   def save() {
      def fooInstance = new Foo(params)
        .addToFavoriteDays(new MyInstant(myInstant: new Instant()))
        .addToFavoriteDays(new MyInstant(myInstant: new Instant()))
        .addToFavoriteDays(new MyInstant(myInstant: new Instant()))

        if (!fooInstance.save(flush: true)) {
          render(view: "create", model: [fooInstance: fooInstance])
          return
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'foo.label', default: Foo'), fooInstance.id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: fooInstance.id)
    }
}
```

Everything saves correctly and the `show` action then shows the new Foo with all the instants.  I've tested this on H2 and MySql.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately ( on Grails 2.2.0 ) that still throws
    failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Missing type or column for column[favorite_days_my_instant] on domain[Foo] referencing[ginstant.MyInstant]. Would an @Type annotation help?

Comment: Have you tried a clean and recompile?  I'm using 2.2.0 as well, and I just tested some more and this works all the way through inserting/retrieving data.  In my `Foo` controller I was able to create the `fooInstance` and add three `MyInstant` objects to `favoriteDays`.  I'll update the answer to show this.

Comment: Yup, tried that. I must be doing something else dumb. Is your MyInstant.groovy in ./src/groovy? No ./grails-app/conf changes?

Could not determine type for: MyInstant, at table: foo, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(birthday)]

Comment: `MyInstant` is a regular Grails domain class in the same package as Foo - that may be why you are getting the error since it won't be a persisted when in `src/groovy`.  No changes to any conf files except BuildConfig.groovy to include JodaTime.  Then created the domains exactly as shown, generated controllers/views and modified the `FooController.groovy` to be exactly as shown.

Comment: You Star! I didn't appreciate that MyInstant was a domain class. Moved it out of ./src/groovy/ and viola!

Comment: Glad to help!  When you get a chance can you accept the answer so it shows as being answered?  Thanks!